# R: Finding the index of a matching value within the same column

Tags: r, indexing

This has been giving me a lot of trouble today and I'm sure there is an obvious solution I'm not thinking of.

I have a data frame of a few thousand rows. There is a column where each value in that column appears exactly twice. I want to locate the index of each matching value. The column looks like so:

```
  col
1 cat
2 dog 
3 bird
4 dog
5 bird
6 cat
```

And I would like to know the corresponding index where the match appears so it would return something like this:

```
[1] 6 4 5 2 3 1
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can do

```
df$new_col <- seq_along(df$col)
df$new_col <- with(df, ave(new_col, col, FUN = rev))
df
#   col new_col
#1  cat       6
#2  dog       4
#3 bird       5
#4  dog       2
#5 bird       3
#6  cat       1
```

In the first step we create a `new_col` as a sequence running from 1 to `nrow(df)`. So this variable is not different from the row numbers.

If we think of variable `col` as defining groups, we get can get 'the corresponding index where the match appears' if we `rev`erse the newly created column by groups of `col` to get desired output.

As a oneliner

```
with(df, ave(seq_along(col), col, FUN = rev))
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(col = c("cat", "dog", "bird", "dog", "bird", "cat"
)), .Names = "col", class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```